# I initaialized the object method below, and it mysteriously cleared my object

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I have this code snippet I made:

```js
var SCP_Object = {
    scp_function:function(){
        var proxy_this={};
        proxy_this.a = 5;
        proxy_this.b = 7;
        return proxy_this;
    },
    get scp_function(){
        this.scp_function.random_string = "Hello, World!";
    }
}

var new_SCP = new SCP_Object.scp_function();
```

When I ran it, I got **RangeError: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded.**, and more curiously, new_SCP was `undefined`, and more curious still, SCP_Object was now an empty object `{}`.

What exactly happened here? I guess it enetered into a forever loop of sorts, but why did it clear the object?

Comment: simpler repro:  `var SCP_Object = { get scp_function() { return this.scp_function; } }; var foo = SCP_Object.scp_function;`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there are a few different things going on here! I'll work through each. First off, the `new` keyword/operator is reserved for JavaScript classes and functions. For this same reason, the below code will throw an error:

```js
let A = {b:2};
new A();
// -> !!! Uncaught TypeError: A is not a constructor
```

I presume here that you would like to set up `SCP_Object` as a class and not just an ordinary object, but I'll deal with this as an object first and then move onto how to work with it as a class.

Getters and setters are perfectly legal to use on regular JavaScript objects, but there are three issues with yours:

1. `new_SCP` will not equal anything because your getter function does casually return anything.
2. Your getter function shares the same name as one of your `scp_function` property, which is illegal. Properties cannot share the same name as getter/setter functions.
3. You are calling the getter with parentheses as if it is a function (`()`), but it is not. You only need to call the property name of the getter and it will return whichever value you set it to return.

Let's resolve these issues:

```js
var SCP_Object = {
  _scp_function: function() {
    var proxy_this = {};
    proxy_this.a = 5;
    proxy_this.b = 7;
    return proxy_this;
  },
  get scp_function() {
    var proxy_this = this._scp_function()
    proxy_this.random_string = "Hello, World!";
    return proxy_this;
  }
}

var new_SCP = SCP_Object.scp_function;

console.log(new_SCP);
```

If you would like to achieve this with a class so you can use the `new` operator, we can do so like this:

```js
class SCP_Object {
  _scp_function() {
    var proxy_this = {};
    proxy_this.a = 5;
    proxy_this.b = 7;
    return proxy_this;
  }
  get scp_function() {
    var proxy = this._scp_function()
    for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(proxy)) {
      this[key] = value;
    }
    this.random_string = "Hello, World!";
  }
}

var new_SCP = new SCP_Object();
new_SCP.scp_function;
console.log(new_SCP);
```

If you'd like to set all those object properties without having to use your proxy functions at all, you can do so within the class itself with ease, whether using a function-style class or a newer ES6-style class:

```js
function SCP_Object_1() {
  this.a = 5;
  this.b = 7;
  this.random_string = "Hello, World!";
}

class SCP_Object_2 {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 7;
    this.random_string = "Hello, World!";
  }
}

var new_SCP_1 = new SCP_Object_1();
var new_SCP_2 = new SCP_Object_1();

console.log(new_SCP_1, new_SCP_2);
```